Running Teensy41 on battery
I'm trying to get my Teensy41 project to run on battery. The docs at the link below seem to indicate that connecting 5v across VIN and GND pins should be enough to run on battery. Initially I am just running the blink program to verify operation without USB connected.
https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy41.html
I have a 5v supply via a LM2596 (Buck converter), in turn powered by 24v Lithium ion battery pack.
When I connect 5v across VIN and GND the program doesn't run. The LED doesn't blink. The red bootloader LED does blink if I press the reset button but the blink program doesn't run. What am I doing wrong?
--
OK. Update. If I start the teensy on USB and then connect battery and disconnect the USB the Teensy does keep running.
So the problem specifically is that the Teensy doesn't start up on battery power.
The problem is the same whether pins are connected or not so it looks like a Teensy / power supply issue and not to do with any of the other peripherals.
Any suggestions?

There are no 5V batteries. What supply exactly you are connecting to the pins and how?

I have a 5v supply via a LM2596 (Buck converter)

That info, in addition to what powers the LM2596, belongs to the question and may explain why it does not work. Please edit the question with this info.

OK. Thank you. Edited now. Any suggestions?

I don't see the schematics of your LM2596 IC, or how you connect it to battery or the Teensy.

Are you sure that you don't have something like while(!Serial) in your code? This would wait for an usb connection

@luni64 bingo! Good suggestion... Thanks v much.
